# Spring Integration subflow depending on .handle method

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to change a flow after particular retry is completed. My IntegrationFlow bean for errorResponse is as follows:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorMailResponse(@Qualifier(ERROR_CHANNEL) PollableChannel errorChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel)
            .handle(MessagingException.class, (payload, headers) -> handleMessageException(payload),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(pollerInterval)))
            .channel(NO_OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
            .get();
}
```

If method `handleMessageException` returns an object I want the flow to continue to particular channel - MAIN_EVENTS_CHANNEL if `handleMessageException` returns null I want to continue to NO_OUTPUT_CHANNEL.

Is that possible to achieve with Spring integration? I tried to use subflow but I am not sure if it is the way. https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorMailResponse(@Qualifier(ERROR_CHANNEL) PollableChannel errorChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel)
            .handle(MessagingException.class, (payload, headers) -> handleMailMessageException(payload),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(pollerInterval)))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(subscription -> subscription
                    .subscribe(subflow -> subflow
                            .<MailPojo>handle((payload, headers) -> {
                                // if if result handleMessageException  == null
                            })
                            .channel(NO_OUTPUT_CHANNEL))
                    .subscribe(subflow -> subflow
                            .<MailPojo>handle((payload, headers) -> {
                               // if result handleMessageException  !=null
                            })
                            .channel(MAIN_EVENTS_CHANNEL)))
            .get();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `null` is not a `payload`. Therefore messaging does not support `null` in most cases. The integration flow just stops at the point where you return `null`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#service-activator-namespace

> The service activator is one of those components that is not required to produce a reply message. If your method returns null or has a void return type, the service activator exits after the method invocation, without any signals.

So, your assumption to make a logical decision is not correct with Spring Integration. You need to think about something what could be used as a signal for such a `NO_OUTPUT_CHANNEL`. You can create an artificial `NullType` and use a `PayloadTypeRouter` to determine when to go next according the payload type returned from your `handleMailMessageException()`:

```
.<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m
                        .channelMapping(MailPojo.class, MAIN_EVENTS_CHANNEL)
                        .channelMapping(NullType.class, NO_OUTPUT_CHANNEL))
```

Another way is to use an `Optional` and check its content in the router function. Either way you need to use a router.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So after `.handle` I add `.route` or remove `.handle` and use ony `.route` instead?

Comment: Both variants are valid. Choose whatever works better for you and easier to understand.

Comment: One more thing: Can I modify the payload in channelMapping or I need to use something else like subFlowMapping?

Comment: No, the purpose of router is just route to this or that channel (or several). The handle and transform are for that purpose. Yes, subFlow could be used as an entry point for the further logic after routing

Comment: Do you mean using `subFlowMapping` llike this:

`.<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m
                        .channelMapping(MailPojo.class, MAIN_EVENTS_CHANNEL)
                            .subFlowMapping(Integer.class, sf -> sf.<MailPojo>handle((p, h) -> handleRetryCounter(p)))
                        .channelMapping(EmptyType.class, NO_OUTPUT_CHANNEL))
                .get();
    }`

In `handleRetryCounter()` I count how many times I try to send the message. If the count is >3 flow should be terminated.

Comment: That’s ok. But you see you do that in the handle. It was wrong to compare mapping with handle. You probably need to learn retry advice instead of that custom logic : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#retry-advice